# How can I dynamically linking my c#.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, compilation

I need dynamically linking in my c#.net application and not static. How can I find if my application is linked dynamically or static and how can I change it to dynamically linked?

I have sarched for a while now and I cannot find a clear answer/instruction how I can change it. 
I need to link dynamically so that I can run my C#.NET application on my windows server with Orcale client Version 12.x (64bit) installed. On my client is Oracle client Version 11.x (32bit) installed and I am not allowed to install version 12.x due to some restrictions.

For now I have the following code added to my Web.config:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <qualifyAssembly partialName="Oracle.DataAccess" fullName="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I have deleted all dlls from oracle in my application directory and now I get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

On my server is `Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.121.2.0` installed. On my client it `Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.3.0` installed.When I change the Version to the server installed version in my qualifyAssembly tag I get a compilation error.

I have added the following code to my web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.3.0" newVersion="2.121.2.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Now I get this error (which has the correct version number that is installed on my server):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The version 2.112.3.0 is installed on my server but how can I reference it?

Comment: Please make your question more clear, and show what the efforts have you done.

Comment: I have added some more informations, hope this is enough... @MirzaDanishBaig

Comment: You need to look into ["Redirecting Assembly Versions"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: what are you actually in need of ?

Comment: I have added the code what I have done so far in my Web.config.
@Constantine please take a look at my updated question

Comment: I have added a few things @MirzaDanishBaig

Comment: @Constantine I ave added some more code and the exception that I get now.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks for the link! It helped me a little bit but now I get another exception and I do not know why this happens because I reference the version that is installed on my server.